MS Word document refuses to be spell checked
I have a bizarre error with Word for Mac, v16.88.
I have a document that I have been working on for a long time. When I run spell check via Review - Spelling and Grammar, it will only check the footnotes and nothing else. It ignores all the body text.
I tried opening a new Word document and typed in some strange words. Then ran spell check. It found them. I then cut and pasted some text from the broken document into this new one. Added some more strange words. Spell check refused to find them.
I selected the broken text and changed it to a standard Word paragraph style. It still won't work.
I cut and pasted the broken text into a plain text editor, then placed it back into the new Word document. Now the spell checker will work, but only with this 'cleansed' text.
Somehow, Word spell checker is broken by some formatting in my document and I cannot find out what.
I have tried every setting in Preferences - Spelling and Grammar, to no avail.

Check the language setting for the misspelled but unflagged words.
Chances are good that the setting for "do not check spelling or grammar" has been checked for those words.
This setting is a type of character formatting. It can be carried in with pasted text.
You can check it by selecting the word and then clicking on the language displayed in the Status Bar.
You can select your entire document and click on the language in the Status Bar and clear that check box.
Here is my article on the Spelling Checker not working.
